# Using animateMotion along with keyTimes/keyPoints

Tags: animation, svg, smil

I am trying to use non-linear animation rate on an SVG [`<animateMotion>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateMotionElement) by using the [`keyTimes="…"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#KeyTimesAttribute) and [`keyPoints="…"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#KeyPointsAttribute) attributes. It does not appear to be working: the animation motion is as linear as can be.

Here's the test file <sup>[try it!](http://phrogz.net/svg/AnimateMotion.svg)</sup>

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 300 200">
  <style>
    path   { stroke:#999 }
    circle { fill-opacity:0.5; stroke:black }
  </style>
  <path   id="p" d="M30,160 L270,40" />
  <circle id="c" r="5" />
  <animateMotion x:href="#c" fill="freeze"
    dur="10s"
    keyTimes="0;0.1;1"
    keyPoints="0;0.9;1">
    <mpath x:href="#p" />
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

When working the ball should move 90% along the path in the first second, and move the final 10% in the remaining 9 seconds. What do I need to change to get this to work?

I've found [another example online](http://hoffmann.bplaced.net/svgtest/animatemotionkeytimes01.svg) that is working correctly, so that I know it's not my OS/browser/version at fault.

<sub>(FWIW: Win7x64, Chrome30)</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my mistake. Even though the default value for `calcMode` is `linear`—which is what I want—I didn't read far enough into the spec to see that it's a *different* default value for `<animateMotion>` elements.

Adding an explicit `calcMode="linear"` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The default `calcmode` Value for animate Motion is `paced` not `linear`;

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateMotionElement

And, if **calcmode = "paced"** is specified, any ‘keyTimes’ or ‘keySplines’ will be ignored.

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#CalcModeAttribute;

That is why you have not got the the desired output...

Comment: Yes, this is the same as the answer I posted. According to [the specs here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#CalcModeAttribute), _"Specifies the interpolation mode for the animation. This can take any of the following values. The default mode is 'linear', however if the attribute does not support linear interpolation (e.g. for strings), the ‘calcMode’ attribute is ignored and discrete interpolation is used."_ However, you are correct that other portions of the spec (a few paragraphs down, and in regions specific to `<animateMotion>`) do change the 'default' value for `<animateMotion>`.