# Start SVG animation time based on a specific date

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I want to create a animation that would last several days to depict the flightpath of apollo 8 to the moon in realtime.

Let's say animation starts on June 10 and ends on June 16.

Is there a way I can load the animation in the middle if a users enters the site on June 13 to show the spacecraft progress?

**Here is my SVG animation so far**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg version="1.1"
         id="svg2" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" sodipodi:docbase="/home/buck/Desktop/Wikipedia" sodipodi:version="0.32" inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape" sodipodi:docname="Apollo 13 timeline.svg" inkscape:version="0.45.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="4.5 180.6 315.2 51.1"
         enable-background="new 4.5 180.6 315.2 51.1" xml:space="preserve">

    <!-- FLIGHT PATH -->
    <path d="M4.9,208
    c1.2,7.9,17.1,12,25.6,14.2c107.2,27.6,273-15.7,285.9-17.5c1.5-0.2,2.7,0.3,3,2c0.2,1.3-0.9,2.4-3,2.4
    c-12.7-0.5-118.1-46.8-272.2-19.9c-11.3,2-26.1,4.4-33.2,8.4c-3.7,2.2-5,5.4-5,5.4s-1.4,2.2-1,5.4"
          stroke="#CECECE" stroke-width="0.619"
          fill="none" id="apollo11"/>

    <!-- EARTH -->
    <path id="path2764" sodipodi:ry="17.946428" sodipodi:type="arc" sodipodi:cy="337.375" sodipodi:cx="276.16071" sodipodi:rx="17.946428" d="
        M16.6,206.9c0,3.1-2.5,5.6-5.5,5.6c-3.1,0-5.6-2.5-5.6-5.5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-3.1,2.5-5.6,5.5-5.6C14.1,201.3,16.6,203.8,16.6,206.9
        C16.6,206.9,16.6,206.9,16.6,206.9z"/>

    <!-- MOON -->
    <path id="path2766" sodipodi:ry="4.987628" sodipodi:type="arc" sodipodi:cy="347.08206" sodipodi:cx="660.63977" sodipodi:rx="4.987628" fill="#646464" stroke="#646464" stroke-width="0.3095" d="
        M318.7,206.9c0,0.9-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5c-0.9,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-0.9,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5C318,205.3,318.7,206,318.7,206.9
        C318.7,206.9,318.7,206.9,318.7,206.9z"/>


    <!-- APOLLO 11 CSM & LEM -->
    <circle cx="" cy="" r="1" fill="black">
         <!--Animation -->
        <animateMotion dur="256s" repeatCount="indefinite">
              <mpath xlink:href="#apollo11"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript to control how the animateMotion should behave.

Here are some hints. This is assuming the visitor comes to your page within the animation playback range.

First, let's define some variables we'll need:

```
var startDate = new Date('2016-06-10'), // when the animation starts
  endDate = new Date('2016-06-16'), // when the animation stops
  today = new Date() // visit date - should be between start and end dates
```

**Setting the right `dur`ation**

Instead of hard-coding the `dur` value, you should compute how much time remains between visit time and the end date.
The animation should keep playing for (in seconds)

```
var remainingDuration = (endDate - today) / 1000 // in seconds
// set this value in "dur" attribute
// e.g. in jQuery: anim.attr('dur', remainingDuration + 's')
```

**Starting the animation at the right moment**

The circle should start at a position proportional to the time elapsed since the beginning of the event:

```
var animationDuration = endDate - startDate
    , timeElapsed = today - startDate
    , percentElapsed = timeElapsed / animationDuration
```

You want the animation to start with the circle position at `percentElapsed` from the `animateMotion` path. This can be controlled with to the `keyTimes` and `keyPoints` attributes:

- `keyTimes` should contain a set of 'points' in time, between 0 and 1 (e.g. 0.5 is halfway through the animation's total duration)
- `keyPoints` is used to tell the progress of the animateMotion animation corresponding to each point in `ketTime`.

[Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#KeyPointsAttribute) for more information.

- `keyTimes` can be hard-coded to `"0;1"`
- `keyPoints` should be set to `percentElapsed +";1"`

P.S. you also have to specify `calcMode="linear"` ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137725))

Here is an example of the animation starting at 25%, using the logic above (although set to run much faster):

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg version="1.1"
         id="svg2" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://web.resource.org/cc/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" sodipodi:docbase="/home/buck/Desktop/Wikipedia" sodipodi:version="0.32" inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape" sodipodi:docname="Apollo 13 timeline.svg" inkscape:version="0.45.1"
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="4.5 180.6 315.2 51.1"
         enable-background="new 4.5 180.6 315.2 51.1" xml:space="preserve">

    <!-- FLIGHT PATH -->
    <path d="M4.9,208
    c1.2,7.9,17.1,12,25.6,14.2c107.2,27.6,273-15.7,285.9-17.5c1.5-0.2,2.7,0.3,3,2c0.2,1.3-0.9,2.4-3,2.4
    c-12.7-0.5-118.1-46.8-272.2-19.9c-11.3,2-26.1,4.4-33.2,8.4c-3.7,2.2-5,5.4-5,5.4s-1.4,2.2-1,5.4"
          stroke="#CECECE" stroke-width="0.619"
          fill="none" id="apollo11"/>

    <!-- EARTH -->
    <path id="path2764" sodipodi:ry="17.946428" sodipodi:type="arc" sodipodi:cy="337.375" sodipodi:cx="276.16071" sodipodi:rx="17.946428" d="
        M16.6,206.9c0,3.1-2.5,5.6-5.5,5.6c-3.1,0-5.6-2.5-5.6-5.5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-3.1,2.5-5.6,5.5-5.6C14.1,201.3,16.6,203.8,16.6,206.9
        C16.6,206.9,16.6,206.9,16.6,206.9z"/>

    <!-- MOON -->
    <path id="path2766" sodipodi:ry="4.987628" sodipodi:type="arc" sodipodi:cy="347.08206" sodipodi:cx="660.63977" sodipodi:rx="4.987628" fill="#646464" stroke="#646464" stroke-width="0.3095" d="
        M318.7,206.9c0,0.9-0.7,1.5-1.5,1.5c-0.9,0-1.5-0.7-1.5-1.5c0,0,0,0,0,0c0-0.9,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5C318,205.3,318.7,206,318.7,206.9
        C318.7,206.9,318.7,206.9,318.7,206.9z"/>


    <!-- APOLLO 11 CSM & LEM -->
  <circle r="1" fill="black">
    <!--Animation -->
    <animateMotion dur="7s" calcMode="linear" keyTimes= "0;1" keyPoints= ".25;1">
      <mpath xlink:href="#apollo11" />
    </animateMotion>
  </circle> \
</svg>
```

**Starting animation after `keyPoints` is set**

You may need to add `begin="indefinite"` attribute to the `animateMotion` , then trigger the animation to start after `keyPoints` and `dur` have been set in javascript, using `beginElement()` [reference](http://properdesign.rs/blog/2015/02/animating-svg-with-beginelement/). I didn't manage to make the animation start using this, I leave it to you as an exercise :)